# Can I embed video using FCKeditor?

Tags: video, fckeditor

I need to create a Wiki using FCKeditor in which I want to provide the flexibility of embedding videos by users. Does FCKeditor support video embedding? If not, are there any plug-ins available for FCKeditor?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it does. Unfortunately I'm not at work today so I can't easily double check, but there is [this](http://www.fckeditor.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9719) and [this](http://www.fckeditor.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=9889) on the FCKeditor forum from 2008. Do these help?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that at my forums: [How to insert a video](http://www.mrfixitonline.com/viewtopic.php?t=3658). 
Here's the code of the plugin: [fck_postvideo.html](http://www.mrfixitonline.com/source.php?file=fckeditor/editor/plugins/postvideo/fck_postvideo.html) and [fckplugin.js](http://www.mrfixitonline.com/source.php?file=fckeditor/editor/plugins/postvideo/fckplugin.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin that simple adds a flash object (supported by default) which is a player and configure it to play some video.

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you are using HTML5 I'm assuming you'll be using Flash to display video. FCKEditor has a built in dialogue box for embedding flash movies.

Take a look at the demo http://www.fckeditor.net/demo and look for the Flash control found on the second row, 6th icon in from the right.