# Problems Embedding Video using FCK Editor

Tags: fckeditor

I am using FCK Editor 2.6.4 and having problems trying to embed a (non-YouTube) video into a content area.

I found this previous question / post:

[EDIT -- as a new user, I am only able to post one link in this post.  The post in question is titled, "Can I embed video using FCK Editor?")

and have investigated all of the proposed solutions, but none of them work properly:

1 -- Using the "Embed Flash" button in the control panel almost works.  However, the video I am attempting to add contains a querystring with parameters, like this:

http://static.animoto.com/swf/w.swf?w=swf/vp1&e=1275795594&f=mGQklEgxXKs9vfEIdGnWsA&d=132&m=p&r=w&i=m&ct=Homes%20in%20Eagle%20Creek&cu=http://hometoindy.com/eagle-creek-real-estate.php&options=

and in using the Flash embed tool, it encodes all of the "&" characters to "& amp;", thus breaking them.  If it were just for me, I could manually change them back, but clients who use this will not know how to do that.

2 -- I have installed the YouTube video plugin, and it works great... for YouTube.  But it cannot be used to embed non-YouTube videos (it automatically changes the URL to YouTube, no matter what).

3 -- I have installed the EmbedMovies plugin, but it throws a javascript error when attempting to add a video file (such as the above) to a page.  (The EmbedMovies plugin page on SourceForge says it has been updated for FCK Editor 2.6, but it does not work.)

4 -- Pasting directly into the editor window (of course) does not work.  The only way I've been able to make this work is by pasting into the Source panel, and this is not a good option for clients who are not familiar with HTML.

So, is there a good, working plugin for FCK editor that will allow me to quickly and easily embed a video such as the one above into a content area?  I don't need to be able to see or preview it in the editor window; I just need it to work when the page is loaded on the front end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given the question you found, and scarcity of answers to that, chances are that the plugin you want does not exist.

If your videos are actually from one, though non-standard, source, I can only repeat my advice from [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747154/can-i-embed-video-using-fckeditor/749194) - write your own plugin. I have code of plugin I wrote linked there, it should be easy to change it to accomodate your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm realizing that all I really need is the Flash plugin that does not encode the querystring characters, because that would allow me to paste in and <embed></embed> code from any online video source.  I will try to work that out and will post the result here if I'm successful.